# How to correctly rewire this outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have an outlet that has 2 live wires that are black and red, 1 black load, 2 neutral and a ground. How can I safely attach these back to the new outlet?

I currently have the neutrals pigtailed. Can I do the same for the 2 live wires?

[image]

Comment: Can you include a picture? It really helps a lot, the experts here can spot details you'd never think to mention.

Comment: Also, your description is ambiguous. Is that two "live wires" _and_ a black and a red (of unknown function), or is that two live wires (comprising a black and a red)?

Comment: It’s two live wires comprising of a black and red. Yeah I’ll get a picture.

Comment: What is the outlet? A general receptacle, some appliance like a light fixture, or something heavier-duty?

Comment: What breaker(s) control the hot wires?

Comment: Picture shows two blacks and a red.  For an outlet/receptacle this might mean you had a split or half switch outlet.  Picture of the old outlet might help.

Comment: Yeah. Was this in a kitchen near a countertop?

Comment: Did you cut the stripped ends off the black wires or were they like that when you opened the box? What's connected by the wire nut hiding in the back of the box? Have you pulled the box completely out of the wall or was there no box there to begin with? Can you post the picture you took of how it was wired _before_ you took it all apart? Oh... Lesson learned!

Comment: The ends of the black cables snapped off when I took them off the outlet. The wire nut is a pigtailed ground cable. No box was there to begin with. The breaker that controls this outlet is the one that is power the lights in the room.

Comment: So you say the outlet had the black cables attached. I assume the white neutrals as well. So where was the red wire attached?

Comment: @Iceman837  Be careful with thinking only one breaker controls this outlet.  The extra red wire might mean two breakers or a switch.  Test don't assume.

Comment: @RibaldEddie I can’t remember what the red wire was attached to but there is an outlet without power when the wires aren’t connected.

Comment: @Iceman837 as the above comment — test, don’t assume. Check the downstream outlet; how many wires are there? If just the two conductor cable, then you probably had a split receptacle. If you still have the outlet that you removed, check to see if the gold contacts have a metal tab that connects them together. If not, then yes you had a split receptacle. If the gold tab is there, then the red is doing something else. From my perspective there not enough info here to make an accurate determination. Test.

Comment: Based on the shepherd's hooks on the red & ground wires and the wire nut, I'm going to assume you're in the US. Having the wiring in the wall like that _without_ a box around it is a code violation. If there's ever a short or arcing that causes heat or a spark, there is no box to contain it, and it can start a fire in your wall. If the fire marshal determines this is the cause of the fire that burns down your house, your insurance company may not pay out. Your first order of business: _Put an old-work box in_. If you're _not_ in the US, it probably makes sense to do so anyway.

Comment: I know this isn't helpful now, but for future DIYers: don't take it apart until you know what's going on. Or, at least, take a picture before you take it apart.

Answer (score 1):

What you likely have is a switched receptacle configuration. The black wire is always hot, and the red wire is controlled by a wall switch.

Another possibility is that it is a mutliwire circuit, where you have 2 hot wires from opposing 240V legs and a shared neutral. This was typically done in the old days (before GFCI was required) for the kitchen countertop appliance circuits. It was actually really nice because you had a very well balanced electrical system.

If you notice, each receptacle has a tab between the two sets of terminals. You can break this tab off to separate the two valves of the duplex receptacle to create two separate circuits. Usually you only break off the hot side for switched receptacles or multiwire circuits, allowing you to have one half switched and one continuous power.

Comment: To add to this — if you had a switched receptacle it would be possible that it was upside down. If you recall if it was upside down (ground prong up) then the red conductor probably goes to a wall switch somewhere in the room.